# how to get weight of each product added to cart in magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am calculating shipping charge for each product with respect to their weight,i want to get each product weight added to a cart separately instead of total weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
$individual_weight=array();
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
$weight = 0;
$weight = ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;
$individual_weight[] = $weight; 
}
```

You will get all the individual product weight stored in the array

Comment: thank you biplab, i have tried but am getting only one product weight which i added last to cart.

Comment: this shouldn't be the case as you are passing the value into an array.